# Gigabyte mainboard: How to enable UEFI graphical bios?

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios, uefi

I recently bought a new mainboard (Gigabyte GA-970-DS3). On of the advertised features is Dual UEFI Bios. I have heard of these nice graphical Bios interfaces and thought that I would have one too.
Unfortunately it has not. If I boot and hit DEL to get into BIOS settings it is just the plain old text interface, no fancy graphics at all.
I looked into the manual but couldn't find anything about it.
So now I wanted to ask you if somebody knows how to enable/get into this interface?
Do I have to enable UEFI somewhere (Windows 7 installation also only detects bios instead of uefi, after preparing it for uefi boot).

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: AFAIK UEFI doesn't mandate any particular setup interface. Maybe they just decided to not spend the money on developing a standalone graphical system setup utility on that particular motherboard and either spent the money elsewhere, or didn't spend it at all? In BIOS/UEFI development, you get *nothing* for free since there's nothing to fall back on. Also, remember that UEFI is a replacement for BIOS, kind of like Linux might be considered a replacement for Windows.

Answer (score 5):

UEFI doesn't guarantee any kind of graphical interface. It provides the **ability** for companies like Gigabyte to create and design their own graphical BIOS.

This is explained fairly well in [the Wikipedia article for UEFI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#Graphics_features).

> So now I wanted to ask you if somebody knows how to enable/get into this interface? Do I have to enable UEFI somewhere

UEFI isn't something that you "enable", it's a specification that defines how the OS interfaces with the hardware. An implementation of the UEFI specification is the software that sits between the two.

Comment: Actually, UEFI is a specification defining how the OS interacts with the hardware. The UEFI implementation *is* that low-level software sitting in between the two.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Thanks for the clarification, fixed. I was thinking that an OS kernel is considered low-level software, then I remembered that we're talking about hardware here, and a kernel is relatively high-level.

Comment: History helps, here. Back in the old days of CP/M, there was BIOS, BDOS and CCP. Hardware manufacturers provided the BIOS, and CP/M provided the BDOS (basically providing file management services) and the CCP (command processor). IBM carried that forward to their PC, providing the BIOS. These days, BIOS is largely being displaced by UEFI, which basically accomplishes the same thing: it provides an abstraction between the operating system's lower layers and the physical hardware. Admittedly, most modern OSes talk directly to the hardware, but they still need a way to bootstrap. Hence UEFI.